# WPF -treeview items can't be selected at 4th level when using datatemplate within datatemplate

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I tried to implement treeview with 4 levels using WPF/C#.Net 4.0.It loads all 4 levels but can't select 4th level and when selecting 3rd level it select group with 4th level.
Continent->Country->District->Artifacts is one structure but there is another one Continent->Products->Artifacts

Resource DataTemplates->

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DistrictTemplates">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">   
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ArtifactName}" />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CountryTemplate">
<TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=District}" 
ItemTemplate="  {StaticResource DistrictTemplates}" 
Header="{Binding Path=Code}">           
</TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

TreeView code->

```
<TreeView Name="treeExplorer" MouseDoubleClick="TreeView_MouseDoubleClick" SelectedItemChanged="treeExplorer_SelectedItemChanged">
 <TreeViewItem Name="tviDefinition" IsExpanded="True" Header="Continent">
<TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Country}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CountryTemplate}" Header="Country" />
</TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

there are some other treeItems as well.I can't use inline template inside the TreeView.Resources and also im confused if can use this HierarchicalDataTemplate sine i cant call Country.Districts.ArtifactName and got two hierarchies but I can call Country.Districts() and then Districts has code property and using code i can find Artifacts.And im using datatemplates inside usercontrol.resources
How would I be able to do this?

Comment: look for HierarchicalDataTemplate

Comment: I checked with that one too but it doesn't work either.i can get districts from country object.district objects can be changed.So to access artifacts we need to first get district code and using that code find the artifact.

Comment: Don't place a Container inside a DataTemplate, which is used in a Container. What i mean is, your DataTemplate contains a TreeViewItem, why? You don't have to and you shouldnt do it, the TreeView takes care of giving each Data Object a proper Container item. Just place the actual content of the TreeViewItem (Icon, Textblock etc.) inside the DataTemplate. Otherwise you will have for one item a visual tree that looks like (TreeView->TreeViewItem->ContentPresenter->TreeViewItem) Also i agree with Jodha an HierarchicalDataTemplate is much more suited for this.

Comment: Hope you understood my problem.Thanks for advices.I'm new to WPF but i checked some examples with this.any explanation why always selecting both level as groups?.Can any put a code without using treeViewItems in Datatemplates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this.Thanks Josh and everyone.

Resource DataTemplates->

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DistrictTemplates">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">   
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ArtifactName}" />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CountryTemplate" DataType="Continent.Countries" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=District}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DistrictTemplates}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code}"/>    
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

TreeView code->

```
<TreeView Name="treeExplorer" MouseDoubleClick="TreeView_MouseDoubleClick" SelectedItemChanged="treeExplorer_SelectedItemChanged">
<TreeViewItem Name="tviDefinition" IsExpanded="True" Header="Continent">
<TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Country}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CountryTemplate}" Header="Countries" />
</TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I've written that goes 4 levels deep.  It's a TreeView which shows HL7 message structure.  For a quick background HL7 is a field separated message.  You have a message.  Each message has a Segment.  Each Segment has at least one field.  A field could have multiple components.  A component can have subcomponents.  This tree displays the HL7 message structure, where each level is a part of the HL7 message format.

For example, if there is  PID segment in the message the tree would like this:

```
PID
...PID.1
...PID.2
......PID.2.1
......PID.2.2
......PID.2.3
......PID.2.4
.........PID.2.4.1
.........PID.2.4.2
```

etc...

Here is the XAML:

```
     <TreeView x:Name="hl7Structure" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MessageSegments}" IsEnabled="True">
        <TreeView.Resources>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyNamespace:MessageSegment}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fields}">
              <TextBox x:Name="segmentName" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyNamespace:MessageField}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Components}">
              <TextBlock x:Name="fieldName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Info}" />
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyNamespace:MessageComponent}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subcomponents}">
              <TextBlock x:Name="componentName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Info}" />
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyNamespace:MessageSubcomponent}">
              <TextBlock x:Name="subComponentName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Info}" />
           </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Now the explanation of how it works.  I have a base object that each HL7 message piece inherits.  The ItemsSource of the TreeView is bound to that collection.  Since there are 4 levels, where 3 show hierarchy and one that does not, there are 3 HierarchicalDataTemplates and 1 DataTemplate.

Think of it this way...The HL7 Message Segment, Field, and Components are tree nodes because they have children.  The HL7 subcomponent is a leaf, because it has none.  Each tree node gets a HierarchicalDataTemplate, but each leaf just gets a DataTemplate.

Each of HierarchicalDataTemplates know what object type to display by using the DataType property.  Here is where I tell the control, the child type it's displaying.  This allows me to use the base type collection and then display all the child types at their appropriate node levels.

Hope this helps.

Comment: there are some other treeItems as well.I can't call inside the TreeView.Resources and also im confused i can use this HierarchicalDataTemplate sine i cant call Country.Districts.ArtifactName but I can call Country.Districts() and then Districts has code property and by code can find Artifacts.And im using datatemplates inside usercontrol.resources.Can any one post suitable sample code.By the this code also helps tx.

Comment: This code sample is relevant.  If you truly have a hierarchical structure, the HierarchicalDataTemplate will work.  From what I can see, your TreeView contains Continents, containing countries, containing districts, containing artifacts.  If you cannot represent this structure easily with a TreeView, then your data is not being constructed correctly.

Represent the data like this:  Start with a collection of continents.  Each continent has a collection of countries.  Each country has a collection of districts.  Each district has a collection of artifacts.

Comment: Also, take dowhilefor's advice and do not put the TreeViewItem in your DataTemplate.

Comment: Continent->Country->District->Artifacts  is one structure but there is another one Continent->Products->Artifacts

Comment: That means your Continent would have a second collection of Products where each product has a collection of Artifacts.  I think all you would need to do is add another Hierarchical Data Template at the appropriate level where the DataType matches on your Products Type.  At that point I think you then need another DataTemplate for your Artifacts.  Let me play around with it and I'll see if I can take what I have above to what you need.